Read from disk using C kernel ATA Qemu
I am making a simple OS, and I want to read letters from disk in C kernel and display them on screen, I am using x86 SeaBIOS on Qemu emulator on M1 Mac. I save data using ata_write(1, 1, data) and read using ata_read(1, 1, buffer). When I write loaded characters to video memory, blank characters are displayed, even though I am setting color bit to 0x0F (white on black).
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int size_t;

typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef char int8_t;

#define VGA_ADDRESS 0xB8000

#define ATA_PRIMARY_IO 0x1F0
#define ATA_PRIMARY_CONTROL 0x3F6
#define ATA_SECONDARY_IO 0x170
#define ATA_SECONDARY_CONTROL 0x376

#define ATA_REG_DATA 0x00
#define ATA_REG_ERROR 0x01
#define ATA_REG_SECCOUNT0 0x02
#define ATA_REG_LBA0 0x03
#define ATA_REG_LBA1 0x04
#define ATA_REG_LBA2 0x05
#define ATA_REG_HDDEVSEL 0x06
#define ATA_REG_COMMAND 0x07
#define ATA_REG_STATUS 0x07

#define ATA_CMD_READ_PIO 0x20
#define ATA_CMD_WRITE_PIO 0x30

#define FS_MAX_FILES 16
#define FS_FILENAME_LEN 32
#define FS_SECTOR_SIZE 512

static inline void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t val) {
    asm volatile("outb %0, %1" : : "a"(val), "Nd"(port));
}

static inline uint8_t inb(uint16_t port) {
    uint8_t ret;
    asm volatile("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(ret) : "Nd"(port));
    return ret;
}

static inline void insl(uint16_t port, void* addr, uint32_t cnt) {
    asm volatile("cld; rep insl" : "=D"(addr), "=c"(cnt) : "d"(port), "0"(addr), "1"(cnt) : "memory", "cc");
}

static inline void outsl(uint16_t port, const void* addr, uint32_t cnt) {
    asm volatile("cld; rep outsl" : "=S"(addr), "=c"(cnt) : "d"(port), "0"(addr), "1"(cnt) : "memory", "cc");
}

void ata_read(uint32_t lba, uint8_t sector_count, void* buffer) {
    outb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_HDDEVSEL, 0xE0 | ((lba >> 24) & 0x0F));
    outb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_SECCOUNT0, sector_count);
    outb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_LBA0, (uint8_t) lba);
    outb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_LBA1, (uint8_t) (lba >> 8));
    outb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_LBA2, (uint8_t) (lba >> 16));
    outb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_COMMAND, ATA_CMD_READ_PIO);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) inb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_STATUS);

    insl(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_DATA, buffer, 128);
}

void ata_write(uint32_t lba, uint8_t sector_count, const void* buffer) {
    outb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_HDDEVSEL, 0xE0 | ((lba >> 24) & 0x0F));
    outb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_SECCOUNT0, sector_count);
    outb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_LBA0, (uint8_t) lba);
    outb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_LBA1, (uint8_t) (lba >> 8));
    outb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_LBA2, (uint8_t) (lba >> 16));
    outb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_COMMAND, ATA_CMD_WRITE_PIO);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) inb(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_STATUS);

    outsl(ATA_PRIMARY_IO + ATA_REG_DATA, buffer, 128);
}


typedef struct {
    char name[FS_FILENAME_LEN];
    uint32_t start_sector;
    uint32_t size;
} file_t;

static file_t fs_files[FS_MAX_FILES];
static uint32_t fs_file_count = 0;


int main(){
    char *v = (char *)VGA_ADDRESS;
    const char* data = "Hello, Disk File System!";
 
    ata_write(1, 1, data);  // Write to sector 1

    char buffer[512];
    ata_read(1, 1, buffer);  // Read from sector 1

    // The letters "H", "e", "l" should be read from disk and displayed
    *(v + 2 * 2) = buffer[0];
    *(v + 2 * 2 + 1) = 0x0F;
    *(v + 3 * 2) = buffer[1];
    *(v + 3 * 2 + 1) = 0x0F;
    *(v + 4 * 2) = buffer[2];
    *(v + 4 * 2 + 1) = 0x0F;
}

Here is my assembly code for setting up disk operations.
; CHS adressing
; cylinder, head, sector

; load 'dh' sectors from drive 'dl' into ES:BX
disk_load:
    pusha
    ; reading from disk requires setting specific values in all registers
    ; so we will overwrite our input parameters from 'dx'. Let's save it
    ; to the stack for later use.
    push dx

    mov ah, 0x02 ; ah <- int 0x13 function. 0x02 = 'read'
    mov al, dh   ; al <- number of sectors to read (0x01 .. 0x80)
    mov cl, 0x02 ; cl <- sector (0x01 .. 0x11)
                 ; 0x01 is our boot sector, 0x02 is the first 'available' sector
    mov ch, 0x00 ; ch <- cylinder (0x0 .. 0x3FF, upper 2 bits in 'cl')
    ; dl <- drive number. Our caller sets it as a parameter and gets it from BIOS
    ; (0 = floppy, 1 = floppy2, 0x80 = hdd, 0x81 = hdd2)
    mov dh, 0x00 ; dh <- head number (0x0 .. 0xF)

    ; [es:bx] <- pointer to buffer where the data will be stored
    ; caller sets it up for us, and it is actually the standard location for int 13h
    int 0x13      ; BIOS interrupt
    jc disk_error ; if error (stored in the carry bit)

    pop dx
    cmp al, dh    ; BIOS also sets 'al' to the # of sectors read. Compare it.
    jne sectors_error
    popa
    ret


disk_error:
    jmp disk_loop

sectors_error:
    jmp disk_loop

disk_loop:
    jmp $


Does anybody know what might be the problem?
Thanks!

You don't wait for the drive to read your data before reading it. Or to finish writing your data first for that matter.

Thanks. How do I fix that?

You wait for it... See e.g. https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode : section Polling the status to get an idea on how to wait for device ready, and also maybe "28 bit PIO" section and "writing 28 bit LBA" for an entirety of the flow you are supposed to follow when reading and writing. There are couple of things you might need to fix.
